# Split a tuple in two chunks based on index

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I wish to build a type that splits a tuple in two chunk based on an index such as

```
type TupleToChunksAt<N extends number, T extends any[]> = // ??

type Test = TupleToChunksAt<1, [1, 2, 3]> // [[1], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwCMUC8sCuYA2EYHsBhACwwDsBreAQWAB4kAaKAbSagCZmBmAXQD4AUKEiwEwDmkw48RUpRr0urdsr5CR0OIm5SYWXARLkqtOgFZmbZmuYAWZpagA2ZgHZmADmYBOAYOFwLQNZYwUzADkoCAAPYAgyABN4KDIMAFsAIwgAJ2YYaLiE5KgAQzIQFgEpQSg62BYAclwyAHNgYkbeQviklKiAfiha+rqWGCteboAuEdGC2N6SlgA6NYBLMgAzXKgAJWZNnZyoAFFugbnR1n0ZI3lTegjmPf4WAAZeKzWV28M5EyKOjPfZvJBfM5TKCza71FhVSa8K51IA) is one solution, although not sure if you want to use it in a real project

Comment: There is a `Slice` utility type in my [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai) package, though I haven't released it yet and it is in this [PR](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/pull/4). By using the `Slice` you could divide the array into two chunks. Here is a bit messy [playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2v84w) with the solutuon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually call this `SplitAt` (but of course you can call it `TupleToChunksAt` and change the type argument order from mine if you want).  The simplest [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) I can think of looks like:

```
type SplitAt<T extends any[], N extends number, A extends any[] = []> =
  N extends A['length'] ? [A, T] : T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
  SplitAt<R, N, [...A, F]> : [A, T];
```

It uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to split/join [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  The accumulator `A` stores the part to the left of the split and is initialized with the empty tuple.  When the length of `A` reaches the desired split location `N`, or when the input tuple is empty, the recursion terminates and we return `A` as the left part and `T` as the right part.  Otherwise we strip the first element off of `T` and append it to `A` and recurse.

You can see that it behaves as desired:

```
type Test = SplitAt<[1, 2, 3], 1>;
// type Test = [[1], [2, 3]]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymA2BLYBBYAeAKlCAPYEAdgCYDOUAhoSANoC6ANFAHI75FlSECuAtgEYQATkxRsCJclVp0oAXij0AfPIBQUFuI7kUNAOTwiAc2AALPbID8ilE0yyAXFGx4JnGokIAzYVABiTAB0wZ4+QlAASlbqsAjIaOgRTMxMNMGBtv50Kk40mfYA3KqqoJDOEKTA8rFIqBg0AIxMAExMAMyMUA1KRQD0vVCl0JgVVQo0jZ00rVAddMVAA)